# Onclick function to active div not working

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a slight problem when trying to set up an edit function on gradient swatches, using active class. Whilst the active class gets set OK in the loop, the subsequent onlick function for the current active class is not performing, here is code below.

```
editSwatch() {
// Get the container element
let gradDiv = document.getElementById("swatch");
    gradDiv.addEventListener("click", function () {
        let current = gradDiv.getElementsByClassName("active");
        // If there's no active class
        if (current.length > 0) {
            current[0].classList.add('active');
        }
        // Add the active class to the current/clicked div
        this.classList.add('active');
        this.current.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log("Current Div is active");
        })
    });
},
```

Current is highlighted with a slight border and works on all the others one by one, but not console log out the message onclick. Another problem is the active does not stick when move mouse away, and need it persistant to set edit and delete functions.

CSS is here

```
#bg-gradient:hover,
#bg-gradient.active {
border: solid 3px rgba(84, 112, 155, 0.7);
}
```

Demo is at [enter link description here](http://living-magic.surge.sh/)

Thanks

Comment: You will have a better chance at being helped if you use a runnable [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). I can spot two problems immediately: `let gradDiv = document.getElementById("swatch");` will always return 1 element, so your for loop on the next line is irrelevant. Also `current[0].className = current[0].className.add(" active", "");` does not make sense, replace it with simply `current[0].classList.add('active')`.

Comment: Also, `let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");` will search for the first element with class `active` in the whole document, not only in `#swatch`! If you want to scope your search and find `.active` elements only in `#swatch`, you should do `let current = gradDiv[i].getElementsByClassName("active");`

Comment: Yes have made those alterations as above, but still not console logging the current div. Have added demo link also Thanks

Comment: Please isolate the problem into a smaller minimal snippet html / js. People trying to help don't have time to go over the whole source code of your website :)

Comment: Ok its just this, the onclick not registering on the current or active div, this        bit below // Add the active class to the current/clicked div
        this.classList.add('active');
        this.current.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log("Current Div is active");
        })

Comment: why is vue.js tagged here?

Comment: Its in a Vue app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you are using `this.current` instead of `current[0]`. Below snippet will help you:

```
function editSwatch() {
 let gradDiv = document.getElementById("swatch");
 console.log('clicked dev');
 gradDiv.addEventListener("click", function () {        
    let current = gradDiv.getElementsByClassName("active");
    console.log(current);
    if (current.length > 0) {
        current[0].classList.add('active');
    }
    current[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log("Current Div is active");
    })
  });
}

editSwatch();
```

Hope this work fine. I think `this` is the culprit here.

Comment: Yes its closer, but still no onlick event on the clicked div, unlkess I run the fucntion from the edit button in header, and then a few hundred or 1000 show up in console.. I cant run editSwatch() (its Vue JS)  I have to use this.editSwatch()

Comment: Couldnt get hat to work so tried another way on this, and it works to a point,, this way they are active when clicked, taken only from the css. I added an id of "gallery" to the main bootstrap row, and looped through like this finding the bg-gradients, it works in as much as that when hover over the image it becomes active (from css) but still wont console log out the message, seems to be a problem getting a console log on click.